# PROGRAM ERROR 1040

Tags: gps, visual-prolog, turbo-prolog

I have this code

```
DOMAINS
    s = symbol.
    sList = symbol*.

PREDICATES
    nondeterm link(s, s,integer).
    nondeterm depth_first_search(s, s, sList,integer).

CLAUSES


    link("Erbil","Koysinjaq",12).
    link("Erbil","Kirkuk",15).
    link("Erbil","Shaqlawa",15).
    link("Erbil","Mosul",22).
    link("Shaqlawa","Akre",33).
    link("Mosul","Duhok",44).
    link("Mosul","Akre",55).
    link("Kirkuk","Koysinjaq",66).
    link("Kirkuk","Chamchamal",88).
    link("Chamchamal","Sulaimani",34).
    link("Koysinjaq","Sulaimani",22).
    link("Sulaimani","Ranya",33).
    link("Akre","Duhok",22).

    depth_first_search(X, X, [X],0).
    depth_first_search(X, Y, [X|T],L):-
        link(X, Z , L1),
        depth_first_search(Z, Y, T,L2),L=L1+L2 .

GOAL
    depth_first_search("Erbil", "Duhok", PathToGoal,Dis).
```

I want to find the shortest path and the distance between two cities , I start form the goal to the start node , count the distance , and return it , but i get that error `PROGRAM ERROR 1040`  while i run it and dont know anything about it , so searched in google , nothing was understandable

Comment: Did you check the Visual/Turbo Prolog help file for 1040? Which version of Visual or Turbo Prolog is this?

Comment: No , I dont think so , I've searched alot , all I got was a long txt file with some errors described

Comment: When I converted the syntax to GNU Prolog it worked fine, so it's something specific to Turbo or Visual Prolog (whatever version you're running). Why are you declaring your facts and predicates `nondeterm`?

Comment: SO , How can I solve it?